# Why are the glyphs included with TBitBtn so ugly and outdated?

Tags: delphi

The glyphs associated with TBitBtn for even Delphi 2010 are choppy and "ugly". Is there a backwards-compatibility reason that they remain? Does Embarcadero include updated png replacements that I could use instead of these normal glyphs?

Maybe it's just me, but I'd love to see Embarcadero solicit (or hire) graphic designers to improve these icons.

[image]

Comment: Personally I'd like to see Embarcadero start using 32bpp glyphs with alpha (as has been possible for 10 years now!) on their own menus in bds. If they did this then they might be moved to remove the horribly broken greying out algorithm for glyphs on menus and replace it with ImageList_DrawIndirect with ImageListDrawParams.fState = ILS_SATURATE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oh how I wish that control would just die :-/... It was introduced in Delphi 1, which targeted 16bit Windows 3.x. At that time little glyphs on buttons were very novel and "dressed up" the UI. (Remember BWCC?) I suppose the UI standards were much lower then, because I cringe every time I see an application with those glyphs... They are mainly included for backward compatibility purposes.

Just stick with a regular TButton, which is a native Windows control and now natively supports more styles than even the TBitBtn (we were vowel challenged in those days, too). If you simply must include a glyph on the button Delphi/RAD Studio XE includes a whole host of free, more modern, glyphs from GlyFX (http://www.glyfx.com/).

Comment: @Allen do you have any opinions of the greying out algorithm for glyphs on menus and how poor it is with 32bpp alpha blended images, as I commented above? I realise I am being a bit cheeky asking you that, but I thought I'd have a go whilst I might be able to get your attenion!!

Comment: TBitBtn is deprecated? A bolt from the blue. Never heard it before. Delphi Help of course is also out of the swim.

Comment: Did I say it was deprecated? Hold on, let me re-read what I wrote... Nope, no mention of deprecation. I merely expressed an opinion.

Comment: @David, I would suggest that you make sure a QC (http://qc.embarcadero.com) is entered as a suggestion. Sometimes in our zeal to maintain backward compatibility, things like this happen. Even then, we've been working to ensure that each release addresses things like this as much as we can.

Comment: @Allen thanks for taking the time to answer this. I have entered a QC. The problem is that you don't use 32 bit alpha glyphs in your product - it's a dogfooding issue! There are quite a few visual flaws in the Delphi menu code that I'd be delighted to help you fix!

Comment: "we were vowel challenged" !! +1

Comment: @David, Agreed. VCL should be much more friendly toward 32bpp/alpha-channel images. 2010 and XE fixed a lot on this front, however we could certainly do better.

Comment: @I can help. In particular there is a major flaw in the VistaDraw approach as presently implemented.

Answer (score 7):

Why are you even using these? Buttons don't need icons. They have enough visual cues without with the advent of uxtheme. Perhaps that's the explanation: why update something that is now legacy?

Comment: +1. I agree. This entire GUI design looks like Windows 3.1.

Comment: @Andreas Ahh, Windows 3.1..... Don't you miss launching your apps from Program Manager? No, I didn't think so!!

Comment: Buttons don't needs icons? Even the Microsoft Design Guidelimes allows for icons "when it is a standard symbol for the command or it helps users visualize the results of the command". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511453.aspx. Of course good icons should be used...

Comment: @Idsandon Glyphs on OK, Cancel, Close, All, No? Really? Which mainstream apps do that today? And as for Ignore, that's a truly bizarre glyph - would you care to offer one that is standard in some way. Glyphs are for tool buttons, command buttons don't need them. Well, that's just my opinion!!!

Answer (score 5):

(Just so that everyone reading this thread gets the big picture: `TBitBtn` <del>boils down to the native Win32 `BUTTON` control</del>, as does `TButton`, but it has some additional properties. One of these is a simple way of displaying an icon next to the caption. Another of these is `Kind`, which can be `bkYes`, `bkNo` etc., and presets the caption and glyph of the button. The standard glyphs are shown above, and indeed, they are old.)

**Update**

After feeling the control, and then having a look at the VCL source code, I see that this control *is* actually implemented in Delphi, that is, all drawing is done manually (using `UxThemes`, of course). This is a major -1, if you ask me, because the button doesn't behave like ordinary Windows controls if Aero is enabled. It feels different.

**End update**

Yes, backward compatibility is probably one thing. Another is that you are free to set the "glyph" to any bitmap you wish. Also, since buttons of this appearance is non-standard in the Windows environment, it probably has rather low priority at Embarcadero.

Nevertheless, to give you some practical information, in Delphi 2009 (at least), there are a few modern PNG images installed at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Images\GlyFX\Icons\PNG\16x16
```

Comment: O, God: "This is a major -1 ...". I have been at SO for too long...

Comment: These controls were created decades ago, when minimizing window handles to conserve resources was far more important.

Answer (score 5):

Backward compatibility to the extreme.

You don't want your Delphi 1 FishFact app to look differently in Delphi XE, do you?

Note that you get a full new set of icons with more recent Delphi versions.
On Windows XP those are in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Images\GlyFX`

--jeroen

Answer (score 3):

I also can't understand why they still don't support PNGs (and other image types) for ALL their components.

Answer (score 1):

[Free replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images) are available.